# How to use native query (insert into) to save data to databse?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem in using spring mvc.
so actually i have repository, service and controller in backend.

story: I want to insert data to the database but in my case i will not gonna use my model because the data that i will save actually will store into another database. so here i use database link.

usually i save the data using model.

StudentService.java

```
public Student save(Student student) {
    return studentRepo.save(student);
}
```

Student Controller

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public Student save(@RequestBody(required = true) Student student) {
    return studentService.save(student);
}
```

but for my case i cant use this.

so my question are :

- is it possible to save using sql native query "insert into" ?
- if it is possible can you give me references for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make your query work :-

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository < UserEntity, Long > {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "insert into students(name, user_id) values(?1, ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
    void insertDate(String firstName, Integer lastName); // sample

}
```

Comment: sir how do i use this repo. should i call it from service and controller ?

Comment: @BusBaru you can  access it directly in your controller or  service class and to execute it just for sample `userRepostory.insertDate("test", Integer.valueOf(12));`

Comment: ha i see. so you mean i just execute it in my web controller (FE MBean).
by that it seems i dont need to create service and controller in backend ?

Comment: @BusBaru just add the method in the repository, and in the controller class add the repository and you can directly execute the method in your controller method

Answer (score 0):

code like these:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserDo {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}

 
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserDo, Integer> {
    //save
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value ="insert into user(id,name) values(?1,?2)")
    int addUserByName(Integer id,String name);
}


@Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Resource
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(UserDo user){
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/User")
public class UserController {
    @Resource
    private UserService userService;
    
    @RequestMapping("/saveUser")
    public String saveUser(){
        UserDo user = new UserDo();
        user.setName("zzz");
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return "userSave success!!";
    }
 
 
}
```

this will work

need to be noticed:`@Transactional()`and `@Modyifing()` is must.